# Good search services for a PHP (CodeIgniter) based job board?

Tags: php, search, codeigniter, search-engine

Does anyone know any good 3rd party license based or open source search services (like Yahoo BOSS) that index and search through content?

I'm creating a niche job board in CodeIgniter and I'd rather not have my search be in PHP.

I'd like the service to be customizable enough to support refining content, and location based searching.  So a really closed tool might not be the right fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe try apache lucene: http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/

Comment: have you implemented in CI

Answer (score 1):

You should try sphider search

you can download sphider folder by

http://www.sphider.eu/download.php

then follow this link for codeigniter

[Integrate Sphider search engine with CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26957556/integrate-sphider-search-engine-with-codeigniter/28039770#28039770)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.